# Occurence frequency by combination (2 by 2)

Tags: r

I have data about customers and the stores they visited (at least one time).

```
Customer | Store

1   A
1   B
2   A
2   C
3   A
4   A
4   B
4   C
```

I'd like to know how many users visited  each **combination of 2** stores.

How can I transform the previous data structure (with R) in order to obtain the following structure ?

```
Store 1 | Store 2 | Nb_Customer
A           B         2     (Customer 1 & 4 visited store A & B )
A           C         2     (Customer 2 & 4 visited store A & C)
```

**Edit** 
About the Henrik's solution : As you can see I have a problem with pair.

```
 # number of visits for each customer in each store 
> df <- data.frame(Customer=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4), Store=c('A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'))
> # number of visits for each customer in each store 
> tt <- with(df, table(df$Customer, df$Store))
> tt

    A B C
  1 1 1 0
  2 1 0 1
  3 1 0 0
  4 1 1 1
> 
> # number of stores
> n <- with(df, length(unique(df$Store)))
> n
[1] 3
> 
> # all pairs of column numbers, to be selected from the table tt
> cols <- with(df, combn(n, 2))
> cols
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    2
[2,]    2    3    3
> 
> # pairs of stores
> pair <- t(with(df, combn(unique(df$Store), 2)))
> pair
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "B" 
[2,] "1"  "3" 
[3,] "2"  "3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
# number of visits for each customer in each store 
tt <- with(df, table(Customer, Store))
tt

# number of stores
n <- with(df, length(unique(Store)))
n

# all pairs of column numbers, to be selected from the table tt
cols <- with(df, combn(n, 2))
cols

# pairs of stores
pair <- t(with(df, combn(unique(Store), 2)))
pair

# select pairs of columns from tt
# count number of rows for which each customer has visited more than one store
# combine the counts with names of stores from 'pairs' to a data frame
ll <- lapply(seq(ncol(cols)), function(x){
  tt2 <- tt[ , cols[ , x]]
  n_cust <- sum(rowSums(tt2) > 1)
  data.frame(store1 = pair[x, 1], store2 = pair[x, 2], n_cust = n_cust)
})
ll

# convert list to data frame
df2 <- do.call(rbind, ll)
df2

#   store1 store2 n_cust
# 1      A      B      2
# 2      A      C      2
# 3      B      C      1
```

Comment: I think there is a mistake with pair.
Wrong stores names appear ar this step (numbers instead of letters)

Comment: Actually I have numbers in string ("2", "3"). I edited my post with the results of your solution

Comment: Perhaps your 'Store' is a `factor`. Check `str(the-name-of-your-dataframe)`. It works fine with 'Store' as a `character`.

Comment: Related to this, you may check/set `options(stringsAsFactors ` to avoid coercion of characters to factors (if you wish) when using `data.frame` or `read.table`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the most efficient way to do this, but it works:

```
df <- data.frame(Customer=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4), Store=c('A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'))

cmb <- t(combn(unique(as.character(df$Store)),m=2))
count <- rep(0,nrow(cmb))

for (i in unique(df$Customer)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(cmb)){
    count[j] <- count[j]+as.numeric(all(cmb[j,] %in% df$Store[df$Customer==i]))
  }
}

res <- data.frame(Store1=cmb[,1], Store2=cmb[,2], Nb_customer=count)

      Store1 Store2 Nb_customer
1      A      B           2
2      A      C           2
3      B      C           1
```

**EDIT:**

And using association rules, you can do it like this:

```
# load library arulas
library(arules)
#original data frame
df <- data.frame(Customer=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4), Store=c('A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'))

# create list
a_list <- lapply(unique(df$Customer),function(x)df$Store[df$Customer==x])

## set transaction names
names(a_list) <- paste("Tr",unique(df$Customer), sep = "")
a_list

## coerce into transactions
trans <- as(a_list, "transactions")

# create association rules
rules <- apriori(trans, parameter=list(minlen=2, maxlen=2, ext=TRUE, originalSupport=FALSE))
# calculate frequency of pairs of stores
rules@quality$abs_support <- rules@quality$support*length(trans)
inspect(rules)


   lhs    rhs support confidence lhs.support lift abs_support
1 {B} => {A}     0.5          1         0.5    1           2
2 {C} => {A}     0.5          1         0.5    1           2
```

`abs_support` is the number of co-occurences

Comment: I have hundreds stores and thousands customers, it takes too much time to use loops.

How can I vectorize this solution ?

Comment: Than use association rules, which is very fast: http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/association-rules

Comment: I don't understand  the link between this and the association rules

Comment: Association rules can tell you, which items (i.e. stores) occur together. You can calculate the frequency of co-occurences of every pair of stores in your data, and it is really fast + you can get another usefull information about statistical probability of those co-occurences etc.

Comment: I edited my answer, so it contains also code for association rules

Comment: I used your code on my data, and some rules are not found.

For instance 4  customers who visited stores A,B and C, and there is not a rule about A and C.

Comment: I suppose you have a very large dataset, in which case you will have to lower minimal support (in list of parameters, add `support=0`).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
d<-data.frame(v1=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4),v2=c("A","B","A","C","A","A","B","C"))
df<-as.data.frame.matrix(table(d))
which(df$A==1 & df$B==1)
which(df$A==1 & df$C==1)
which(df$B==1 & df$C==1)
```

Comment: I have much more stores and combination. I can't list all of them like you do.

Comment: Do you want to consider the cases where the customers visited the stores at least one time or exactly once?